# Get enitity ID after programatically creating one

Tags: 7, entities

I have a the following code:

```
// Create an Entity with wrapper
  $node = entity_create('node', array('type' => 'person'));
  $entity = entity_metadata_wrapper('node',  $node);

  // Add a node title
  $entity->title = $person['name'];

  // Add the address information
  $entity->field_person_address->thoroughfare = $person['address'];
  $entity->field_person_address->locality = $person['city'];
  $entity->field_person_address->administrative_area = $person['state'];
  $entity->field_person_address->postal_code = $person['postalcode'];
  $entity->field_person_address->country = $person['country'];

  // Save the entity
  $entity->save();
```

The data is saved in the DB perfeclty, but I need to get the entity ID of the new save node.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use

```
$entity->save();

$nid = $entity->nid->value();
```

Answer (score 23):

You can use [getIdentifier()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!includes!entity.wrapper.inc/function/EntityDrupalWrapper%3A%3AgetIdentifier/7) method of the wrapper.

```
$node = entity_create('node', array('type' => 'person'));
$entity = entity_metadata_wrapper('node',  $node);
$entity->save();
$entity->getIdentifier();
```

Comment: _Much_ better than the direct way, good find

Comment: Up vote for entities that are not nodes